# How do I use a input to turn off Lines.new

Tags: input, line, pine-script-v5

Im trying to create a switch a On/off switch for Line.new but im not sure how to go about it

```
ShowAsiaRange = input.bool(true,'Show Asia Range', group= M1)

tl = line.new(LineFromDate, rth_low, LineToDate, rth_low, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=line_color, style=upperlower_line_style, width=sessionLineWidth)
line.delete(tl[1])

th = line.new(LineFromDate, rth_high, LineToDate, rth_high, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=line_color, style=upperlower_line_style, width=sessionLineWidth)
line.delete(th[1])

tm = line.new(LineFromDate, rth_mid, LineToDate, rth_mid, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=user_midline_color, style=middle_line_style, width=Width)
line.delete(tm[1])
```

I have tried the if function but to no avail so im stuck here, Im also new to pinescript so I am searching for help

Answer (score 0):

in pinescript v5, you can use :

```
draw = input.bool(true,"draw line ?")
var line1 = line.new(draw?bar_index-10:na, draw?low:na, bar_index, low, extend=extend.right, color = color.green)
```